# What if NSZombie itself throws an NSException? _NSZombie_NSException

Tags: ios, xcode, nszombie

I ran into an EXC_BAD_ACCESS unexpectedly. This is using XCode 4.5 and iOS6 as target, using ARC.

Enabling Zombies gives me this:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class '_NSZombie_NSException'
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Looking through other posts here on SO and elsewhere, enabling Zombies is supposed to show you where in your code you may be having memory allocation issues. But this error points to `@autoreleasepool` and seems to raise an exception to the NSZombie class itself?

Comment: Set an exception break point, make sure you're not over releasing anything, and can you post the rest of the exception stack trace?

Comment: Setting a "catch all" exception breakpoint did the trick! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!